# does tSQLt support comparing two JSON strings?

Tags: tsqlt

I am using tSQLt to test stored procedures which output JSON string results. The problem I have is that the key/value pairs in JSON are not always the same order. For example,
JSON1: {"A":1, "B":2}  and  JSON2: {"B":2, "A":1}

tSQLt.AssertEqualsString will fail when compares JSON1 with JSON2. I expects the test to be passed if only the order is different.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no direct way to compare JSON in tSQLt.

However, one way you could deal with that is by splitting the JSON into a key/value pair table. You can for example use [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) for that.

Once the values are in rows, you can use [tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable](https://tsqlt.org/user-guide/assertions/assertequalstable/) to compare the expected result to the actual result.